# Is it possible to have multiple Build Rules for a single file glob/pattern in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, build-automation

You can make custom build rules for files that match a particular pattern, e.g. `*.m` for Objective-C sourcecode. If you do this, those files will no longer be compiled, it seems to override existing rules.

Is it possible to create multiple build rules for a particular file type (such as `.m` files), and have them both run during a build, so you could have Xcode compile the source normally, but also run them through some other script/utility?